# Neither Invalidate() nor Refresh() invokes OnPaint()

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to get from Line #1 to Line #2 in the below code:

```
using System;  
using System.Windows.Forms;  

namespace MyNameSpace  
{  
    internal class MyTextBox : System.Windows.Forms.TextBox  
    {  
        protected override void OnEnabledChanged(EventArgs e)  
        {  
            base.OnEnabledChanged(e);  
            Invalidate(); // Line #1 - can get here  
            Refresh();  
        }

       protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)  
       {
            base.OnPaint(e);   
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break(); // Line #2 - can't get here  
       }  
    }  
}
```

However, it seems that neiter Invalidate() nor Refresh() causes OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) to be invoked. Two questions:

1. Why doesn't it work?
2. If it can't be fixed: I only want to invoke OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) in order to access the e.Graphics object - is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To override the drawing of the control, you must set the style to be UserPaint like this:

```
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
```

See this for more information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.setstyle.aspx

> UserPaint If true, the control paints
>   itself rather than the operating
>   system doing so. If false, the Paint
>   event is not raised. This style only
>   applies to classes derived from
>   Control.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: After reading Chris's comment I agree you probably should not use this.

---

To answer the other part of the question, you can get a graphics object for an arbitrary control with:

```
 Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics();
```

But when doing that, you are also responsible for cleaning it up so the correct form is:

```
  using (Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics())
  {
     // all your drawing here
  }
```

Comment: But should probably not do this.  Check this link:  http://www.bobpowell.net/creategraphics.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
internal class MyTextBox : System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
{
    public MyTextBox()
    {
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
}
```